# Code Completion using CodeIgniter on Espresso

Tags: php, ide

I have downloaded Espresso to use as a PHP (CodeIgniter) IDE, but it appears that Espresso doesn't have code completion for CodeIgniter.

Is there anyway that I can enable the code completion in Espresso, or download a plugging in which I can enable this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [Codelobster PHP Edition](http://www.codelobster.com)
It has special plug-in for CodeIgniter auto-completion.

Comment: Thanks, but I am using a mac.